# trying to populate dropdown list with php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

i am trying to populate the dropdown list with PHP but i keep getting one blank cell apart from the select option! any help is appreciated!

```
                  <fieldset id="Amount">
              <?php
              include ("connect.php");
              $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
              if(!db) {
                exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_error() . ') '
                     . mysqli_connect_error());
              }
              ?>
              <label><span class="text_9">AMOUNT:</span></label>
              <select required name="amount" id="amount">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <?php
              $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT 'Amount' FROM 'Contracts'");
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->bind_result($amt);
              while ($stmt->fetch_()){
                  echo "<option value='$amt'></option>";
              }
              $stmt->close();
              ?>
              </select>
              </fieldset>
```

Thank you!

Comment: can u post sample output please?

Comment: [link](http://demo9182.bam.com.sg/preorder_1.html)

Comment: can you confirm that there is no blank record when you are executing your query on the database manually?

Comment: in the database there is no blank record in the Amount column

Comment: based on your link... try to inspect element.. try to convert the page to `php`

Comment: i want to keep it html for other elements...how do i link a php page to the dropdown list?

Answer (score 1):

remove single quote from the table name and change it to :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT 'Amount' FROM Contracts");
```

and make sure you have data in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this keep html out of php block

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT 'Amount' FROM 'Contracts'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($amt);
while ($stmt->fetch_()){
?>


<option value="<?php echo $amt; ?>"> <?php echo $amt; ?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Still does not work--> same issue. Is there a way i can have a php in another file and call it in the Option value?

Comment: try to put
print_r($amt) after $stmt->bind_result($amt);
then tell me what it prints

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Comment: i think the problem is in your query first you get proper data from database  you can interact with database through PDO its simple

Comment: hi @Noor i tried using PDO for this with the following php: `<?php
$ops='';
include "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT Amount FROM Contracts");
//$stmt = $pdo->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}
?>
` However, when i open the php page, it is blank :(

Comment: `<?php 
$ops=''; 
include "connect.php"; 
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT Amount FROM Contracts"); 
$stmt = $pdo->execute(); 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
 echo $row['Amount']."<br/>";
} ?>`
try this one

Comment: can i just call this php file using `                  <select name="amount">
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  <?php echo $ops;?>
                  </select>
`